# How do I setup a Microsoft Word 2011 template that allows two pictures per page with room for text under each?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I am setting up a form that will be used for inspection reports.  I am running Mac OSX (10.8.5) with office 2011 using word.  I would like to have the area for the pictures predefined so that I just drag and drop them into the file.  I have seen this before, but do not know how it is done.  I would also like to have text boxes under the images so I can just tab through to the text as the form is being filled out.  Basically I need the pictures to have a predefined location and size after dragging them in.  Am I dreaming?

Answer (score 1):

Although I believe this to be much easier with PowerPoint, you could try to setup a "2 column page" in Word and get what you need. You can also predefine your image size with any editor to resize them. This, of course, depends on your page size and layout (I.E. landscape, portrait, custom).

Good luck